# My app doesn't look the same on different devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

My app looks perfect in my Samsung S3 Neo , but when I tried to download the app on a different device it looked completely different.
Here the pics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8aXo.jpg ( the last pic is what I'm trying to fix and it doesn't display the banner , but on my s3 neo it's all perfect)
Do you know what should i do? Thank you in advance.

Here the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity"
android:background="@drawable/sfondonero">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7226926424148914/1067724781"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="173dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/aidsv"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="@drawable/redbottone"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="   Score:"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:background="@drawable/sfondotempo"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: So basically you want the button to be below the image, correct? use the layout_below attribute on your button so that it's below the image. You've done a similar one for your TextView so all you need to do is to set it on your button as well. You're fixing widths and margins though. This will prove to be problematic in the future for you when you work with smaller/larger phones and tablets. Try to use @dimen so that you can control the size by a config or use stuff like wrap_content/match_parent where possible so that it resizes properly on all devices.

Comment: Yes @kha , I'm trying to put the button below the red ribbon , but above the score field. Also i would like the banner to display correctly on different devices. The app looks perfect(banner included )in Galaxy s3 neo , but it doesn't in Galaxy s plus. Tonight i will try to fix the problem and i will tell you if it works or not.Thank you.

Comment: Sure. use the relative positions I told you (layout_below) and it'll work fine. you want your button below image and your text below your button. Give your image and button an id (button already has one) and then use the layout_below.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but in the banner I would substitute the last four lines with:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I see you used it in the ImageView so I don't understand why you didn't use it in the banner.